# How to get buffer filename to appear in the ledger-report command?

Tags: ledger

I work on different ledger files. Currently, each time I call `ledger-report` I have to retype the command `ledger -f [filename] bal`. How can I get the current buffer filename to appear by default in this command?

Comment: There is a variable `ledger-reports` which can be customized to contain the entire command including a dynamic determination of the filename derived from the `(current-buffer)`.  If a predefined command does not exist in `ledger-reports`, then the default behavior is to memorize the new command and add it to the aforementioned variable and store it in the `.emacs` file for future use.  I am careful not to type in new commands that have not been predefined because I don't want to populate the `.emacs` file.  Instead, I just use the down arrow key to select from the available choices ...

Comment: Here is the Github link to the exact location where the variable `ledger-reports` (which can be customized) is defined with four (4) default settings of `bal`, `reg`, `payee`, and `account`:  https://github.com/ledger/ledger-mode/blob/master/ledger-report.el#L47  You can get very elaborate when creating custom commands, especially if you decide to use a little bit of Lisp to take full control over the variable `ledger-reports` and instead forego `M-x customize-variable` ....  Or, you could just use the aforementioned command.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks, that solved it! Upvoting now but can't select as correct answer since it's in comments.

Comment: @lawlist: please consider making your comment an answer.